# Updating Child Component Via Change of Props from Parent in React

Tags: reactjs, components, render, jsx

I have a component whose state is passed as a prop to a child component. I noticed that even if the Parent's state is changed, the child component is not re-rendered.

Based on the official React Documentation for utilizing shouldComponentUpdate:

> "The first time the inner component gets rendered, it will have { foo:
>   'bar' } as the value prop. If the user clicks on the anchor, the
>   parent component's state will get updated to { value: { foo: 'barbar'
>   } }, triggering the re-rendering process of the inner component, which
>   will receive { foo: 'barbar' } as the new value for the prop.
>
> The problem is that since the parent and inner components share a
>   reference to the same object, when the object gets mutated on line 2
>   of the onClick function, the prop the inner component had will change.
>   So, when the re-rendering process starts, and shouldComponentUpdate
>   gets invoked, this.props.value.foo will be equal to
>   nextProps.value.foo, because in fact, this.props.value references the
>   same object as nextProps.value.
>
> Consequently, since we'll miss the change on the prop and short
>   circuit the re-rendering process, the UI won't get updated from 'bar'
>   to 'barbar'."

If I can't use shouldComponentUpdate, how would I force the child component to re-render based on a change of props from the Parent?

Parent Component

I want the child component to rerender based on the boolean given to showDropzone.

```jsx
     <Dropzone 
      onDrop={this.onDrop} 
      clearFile = {this.clearFile}
      showDropzone = {this.state.filePresent}/>
```

Child Component

```jsx
export default class Dropzone extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { onDrop } = this.props;
    const {showDropzone} = this.props;
    const {clearFile} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="file-adder">
          <div className="preview">
            {{showDropzone}? 
            <Dropzone
              onDrop={onDrop}
              ref="dropzone">
            </Dropzone>           
            :<button type="button" 
            className="btn btn-primary"
            onClick={clearFile}>
            Clear File</button>}
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the naming is correct? The child component is called Dropzone, but its render function also renders a child <Dropzone>.

Answer (score 3):

I'am sorry but your code has a lot of errors

First (This is a tip) inside:

```
 const { onDrop } = this.props;
 const { showDropzone } = this.props;
 const { clearFile } = this.props;
```

You can write just one line

```
 const { onDrop, showDropzone, clearFile } = this.props;
```

---

Now your problems starts from here:

> You used showDropzone inside **curly brackets** and this is your
>   problem remove them

Your mistake `{{showDropzone}? firstOption : anotherOption }`

Will be `{ showDropzone? firstOption : anotherOption }`

---

Another mistake:

> You used the **Dropzone** component inside itself and this is a big mistake

You can't use Dropzone component here `{{showDropzone}? <Dropzone {...}/> : anotherOption }` You can use it from another component

---

Finally i tried to format your code to make it like this

Parent Component

```
{ this.state.filePresent
   ? <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop} />
   : <button
         type="button" 
         className="btn btn-primary"
         onClick={clearFile}
         children="Clear File"
     />
}
```

Child Compnent

```
class Dropzone extends Component {
  render() {
    const { onDrop } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="file-adder">
        <div className="preview" onDrop={onDrop} ref="dropzone">
          <p>Hi! This is Dropzone component</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dropzone;
```

Answer (score 0):

In child component you have used "showZone" instead of "showDropzone".

Thanks

Comment: thanks! That was a minor mistake on my part I tried it and it still doesn't work

Comment: Do you want to update that state on Button Click "clearFile" ?

Comment: the state showZone updates to true and false in the parent component. I can update the parent states. My problem is in the child component, only the <Dropzone> component shows. The clear file button never shows even though I have a  {{showDropzone}?  to check if showDropzone is true or false

Comment: Can you please try that condition in render method using an variable and render that variable in return and also bind that onclick with this:
 render(){
    var showButton = 
    if(this.props.showDropzone){
 showButton  = <Dropzone
         onDrop={this.props.onDrop}
         ref="dropzone">
        </Dropzone>  
    }
    else{
       showButton  = <button type="button" 
        className="btn btn-primary"
        onClick={this.props.clearFile.bind(this)}>
        Clear File</button>
    }
   
   return(
     <div>{showButton}</div>
   )

}

Comment: Thanks I'm not sure if the syntax is correct, I will work on this tonight